# Performing subtraction operation on csv fields

Tags: powershell

Here is what I want to accomplish: `ackedepoch - startepoch = timetoack`
Subtracting two values and write the result to the third field.
Example values:

```
ackedepoch 1685978483
startepoch 1685861681
timetoack  0
```

I get an error saying this:

```
Cannot convert value "ackedEpoch" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:2 char:3
+   $field.timetoack = $field.ackedepoch - $field.startepoch
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

Code:

```
$parsedbody2 = Import-Csv -Header ("id","startepoch","ackedepoch","timetoack") -path C:\windows\temp\parsedbody2.csv
Foreach ($field in $parsedbody2) {
    $field.timetoack = $field.ackedepoch - $field.startepoch
}
```

Parsedbody2.csv

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"id","startEpoch","ackedEpoch","timetoack"
"DS1622894","1685861681","1685978483","0"
"DS1622976","1685893279","1685978483","0"
"DS1753568","1686083327","1686084500","0"
"DS1754127","1686753055","1686840339","0"
"DS2432755","1689110401","1691429460","0"
"DS2432979","1689394902","1691429460","0"
"DS2432980","1689394902","1691119366","0"
"DS2433464","1689867662","1691429460","0"
"DS2469117","1691857276","1692027433","0"
"DS2623616","1693413107","1695310712","0"
"DS2624283","1694198166","1695310712","0"
"DS2624511","1694574968","1695400492","0"
"DS2624892","1695075300","1695310712","0"
"DS2624899","1695105316","1695310712","0"
"DS2624965","1695158163","1695310712","0"
"DS2840077","1696475587","1696485368","0"
"DS2840079","1696477987","1696485365","0"
"DS2878278","1696480761","1696485348","0"
"DS2878280","1696482630","1696485344","0"
"DS2878282","1696484430","1696485330","0"
"DS2878287","1696495230","1696522182","0"
"DS2878289","1696498830","1696522183","0"
"DS2878329","1696522213","1696522671","0"
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine, the issue is that `-Header` is only needed when the Csv does NOT have headers, and yours already has. So you can ignore that part :) `$parsedbody2 = Import-Csv -path C:\windows\temp\parsedbody2.csv` and the code is fine